# Using aggregate (Count) on a linked SQL table

Tags: sql, count, aggregate-functions, firebird

I have a table called ITEMMASTER. I also have a tabled called BOMMASTER (BOM is Bill Of Materials). Each have a field ITEMCODE but are not directly linked. There is another tabled called BOMLINES. A BOMMASTER will have 1 to many BOMLINES.

I want to get a result that shows The ITEMMASTER, the equivalent BOMMASTER and the total number of lines used in the BOM. However when I used the aggregate COUNT(tablename.fieldname) it comes back with an error "SQL error code -104 Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.)

The (Firebird) SQL query I used was:

```
SELECT
ITEMMASTER.ITEMCODE, 
BOMLINES.ITEMCODE, 
COUNT(BOMLINES.LINECODE)
FROM BOMLINES, ITEMMASTER
WHERE ITEMMASTER.ITEMCODE = BOMLINES.ITEMCODE
GROUP BY BOMLINES.ITEMCODE
```

I also tried LEFT JOIN but got the same error.

I know the following code works:

```
SELECT 
BOMLINES.ITEMCODE, 
COUNT(BOMLINES.LINECODE)
FROM BOMLINES BOMLINES
GROUP BY BOMLINES.ITEMCODE
```

But I want to link it to the ITEMMASTER table so I can add an additional WHERE clause on an ITEMMASTER fieldname.

I imagine I am missing something very basic.

The purpose of the COUNT() is to work out how many BOMLINES there are for each BOM. I don't care what the BOMLINES are, just how many there are.

So the following worked:

```
SELECT
ITEMMASTER.ITEMCODE,
ITEMMASTER.ADDITIONALFIELD_6,
COUNT(BOMLINES.LINECODE)
FROM BOMLINES 
JOIN ITEMMASTER ON ITEMMASTER.ITEMCODE = BOMLINES.ITEMCODE
GROUP BY ITEMMASTER.ITEMCODE, ITEMMASTER.ADDITIONALFIELD_6
ORDER BY ITEMMASTER.ITEMCODE, ITEMMASTER.ADDITIONALFIELD_6
```

So I need to mention ALL the fields listed in the SELECT in the GROUP BY section? That seems quite cumbersome. Thank you BWS

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Firebird supports analytical functions right? https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs.html  Also think about your display.  If you want to show the specific items, what "Count" are yo looking for by item or total count of items?  Mock up some expected results I think it will help clairify your question.

Answer (score 2):

As the error states, you need to include all the items in the SELECT in either an aggregate or group by... so, do one of the following:

```
SELECT
ITEMMASTER.ITEMCODE, 
BOMLINES.ITEMCODE, 
COUNT(BOMLINES.LINECODE)
FROM BOMLINES
JOIN ITEMMASTER ON ITEMMASTER.ITEMCODE = BOMLINES.ITEMCODE
GROUP BY BOMLINES.ITEMCODE, ITEMMASTER.ITEMCODE
ORDER BY BOMLINES.ITEMCODE
```

-or, simply-

```
SELECT
BOMLINES.ITEMCODE, 
COUNT(BOMLINES.LINECODE)
FROM BOMLINES
JOIN ITEMMASTER ON ITEMMASTER.ITEMCODE = BOMLINES.ITEMCODE
GROUP BY BOMLINES.ITEMCODE
ORDER BY BOMLINES.ITEMCODE
```

since ITEMCODE from both tables will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

A few things about your question

1. You don't define how BOMMaster relates to BOMLine
2. You don't indicate what exactly your count is attempting to represent. (# of lines on a BOM?, A count of items on the BOM (if the same item is on multiple lines should we count 1 or 2?)
3. Are you aware of analytical (window) functions?

.

```
SELECT ITEMMASTER.ITEMCODE, 
       BOMLINES.ITEMCODE, 
       COUNT(BOMLINES.LINECODE) over (partition by BOMMaster.BomCode) as BOMItemCount
FROM BOMLINES
INNER JOIN ITEMMASTER
  ON ITEMMASTER.ITEMCODE = BOMLINES.ITEMCODE
INNER JOIN BOMMASTER
  on BOMMaster.BOMCode = BOMLines.BOMCODE
GROUP BY BOMLINES.ITEMCODE, BOMLines.ItemCode
```

The above count uses a window function to get the count of lines on a given bomcode assuming bomcode is the primary key of BomMaster.

Comment: Window functions are pretty new in Firebird (they were introduced in version 3 released last year).